# How to use a thread to break a loop in main c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using the following thread in c++ to check if a certain condition is met and if so then it should break the loop. I call the thread in a while loop so I need that to break.
The refresh token is updated by another thread.

```
void ThreadCheck( void* pParams )
{
  if(refresh)
  {
      continue;
  }
 }
```

My while loop:-

```
while(crun)
{
    refresh = false;
    _beginthread( ThreadCheck, 0, NULL );
    rlutil::setColor(8);
    cout<<"Send>> ";
    getline(cin, msg); //Make a custom function of this.
    if(stricmp(msg.c_str(), "exit")==0)
    { 
        crun = false;
    }
    else if(msg.empty() || stricmp(msg.c_str()," ")==0)
    {
       rlutil::setColor(4);
       cout<<"Plz enter a valid message!\n";

       continue;

    } else {
    manager('c', msg);
    // msg.append("\n");
    // chat_out<<msg;
    // chat_out.close();
        }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Shall we discount the fact that the `continue` in the thread proc isn't even valid?

Comment: Yes, the continue isn't valid but that is why i need to know how i coud achieve the same.

Comment: Before someone starts spewing a viable solution that uses the standard C++11 threading library, can you update your question and include the toolchain you're building with (specifically, is it VS2010, VS2012, something else?). It makes a difference.

Comment: @WhozCraig: very good point!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify a value in one thread while another thread is, or might be, accessing it. You need to use some form of synchronization, such as a lock.

Comment: You can, the question is, should you? ;)

Comment: Well, you *can*, but the effects are unpredictable.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could elaborate since it is hard do comprehend since I am new to threading.

Comment: @GPTBoss: It is your responsibility to make sure you *never* modify a value in one thread while another thread is, or might be, accessing it. (Unless that value is some special type of value that specifically defines the behavior of this kind of operation.) How you do this is your business, but you *must* do it.

Comment: You can and it is predictable if you know what you're doing. Like you said.. using some synchronization technique should bring him where he wants to get.

Comment: @GPTBoss: You cannot expect an operation which not atomic (i.e. will complete without interruption) will be completely executed. Therefore, due to the implication of shared memory architectures and thread scheduling (the operating system decides when to run what), you could have thread T1 try write to variable A, but since thread T2, which tries to do the same, is scheduled just before T1, T2 will have written to A first. It might be the other way around the next time the threads try to do this. Thus, unpredictable.

Comment: @StefanFalk It is predictable only in the sense that you will for sure get _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 threads : 1) main, 2) ThreadCheck. Add a mutex so as not to update the 'crun' at the same time and inside the thread update the value to false. That's it

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/tbb/mutex.h"
#include "/tbb/tbb_thread.h"
using namespace tbb;

typedef mutex myMutex;
static myMutex sm;
int i = 0;

void ThreadCheck( ) 
{ 
      myMutex::scoped_lock lock;//create a lock
      lock.acquire(sm);//Method acquire waits until it can acquire a lock on the mutex
         //***only one thread can access the lines from here...***
        crun = false;;//update is safe (only one thread can execute the code in this scope) because the mutex locked above protects all lines of code until the lock release.
         sleep(1);//simply creating a delay to show that no other thread can update 
         std::cout<<"ThreadCheck "<<"\n";
         //***...to here***

      lock.release();//releases the lock (duh!)      
}

int main()
{
   tbb_thread my_thread(ThreadCheck);//create a thread which executes 'someFunction'

   // ... your code

   my_thread.join();//This command causes the main thread (which is the 'calling-thread' in this case) to wait until thread1 completes its task.

}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example. I am new to it.

Comment: See also : http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SYNCHRONIZATION